# ¿Que significa en C que escriba puntero1->puntero2->punrero3?

Tags: c, variables, punteros, struct

Para mi entender: el puntero 1 esta direccionado a la estructura del puntero2 y el puntero2 esta direccionado al puntero3, pero no estoy muy segura. Alguno sabría como explicarlo mejor para poder entenderlo?
Perdón por la pregunta tan básica.

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para que sea lea puntero1->puntero2->puntero3 (nota la sustitución en puntero3).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La sintaxis "flecha" como en:

```
a->b
```

sólo puede usarse si `a` es un puntero a un tipo `struct`, del cual `b` es un campo. El compilador lo convierte a esto otro, que es equivalente:

```
(*a).b
```

Es decir, se *desreferencia* el puntero `a` mediante `*a`, de modo que `*a` es la estructura a la que apuntaba, y entonces ya podemos acceder al campo `b` de esa estructura.

Puedes escribir `(*a).b` si te resulta más claro, pues es totalmente equivalente a `a->b`, siendo la segunda forma un simple [*syntactic sugar*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) de la primera.

No obstante este *sugar* resulta útil cuando empiezas a tener campos de estructuras que son en realidad punteros a otras estructuras. Imagina en el ejemplo anterior que el tipo de `b` es también puntero a `struct`, y que quieres acceder al campo `c` de la estructura apuntada por `b` (el cual es un campo de la estructura apuntada por `a`).

La sintaxis explícita, desreferenciando los punteros, se vuelve farragosa:

```
(*(*a).b).c
```

si la lees con detenimiento entenderás lo que hace. La versión *azucarada* resulta en este caso mucho más legible:

```
a->b->c
```

Insisto sin embargo en un punto importante. Esta sintaxis no es para cualquier puntero, sino exclusivamente para punteros a estructuras, siendo lo que hay a la izquierda de la flecha el puntero y lo que hay a la derecha un campo de la estructura apuntada.

Por completar el ejemplo, esta sería una posible declaración de la variable `a` (naturalmente habría que inicializarla adecuadamente, pues sin la inicialización el intento de acceder a `a->b` daría probablemente un *segfault*).

```
struct demo {
   struct demo *b;
   int c;
} *a;
```

Comment: Entonces en el caso de  a->b->c  seria un puntero apuntando a una estractura que apunta a otra estructura?

Comment: Siendo un poco más precisos, sería un puntero apuntando a una estructura, que tiene un campo que es otro puntero que apunta a otra estructura. En el ejemplo que he puesto `a` apunta a una estructura, uno de cuyos campos es `b` que apunta a otra estructura (en este ejemplo, del mismo tipo que la primera), que tiene un campo llamado `c`. En este ejemplo no quise complicar más y dejé que `c` fuese `int`, pero podría ser puntero a otra estructura. En realidad esto también sería válido: `a->b->b->b->b->c`

Comment: Ah,ahora lo entendi mejor,gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Supongamos que tenemos la estructura `punto`

```
struct punto {
    int x;
    int y;
}
```

Si una estructura grande va a ser pasada a una función, generalmente es más eficiente pasar un apuntador que copiar la estructura completa. Los apuntadores a estructuras son como los apuntantadores a variables ordinarias. La declaración

```
struct punto *ap
```

dice que `ap` es un apuntador a una estructura de tipo `struct punto`. Si `ap` apunta a una estructura `punto`, `*ap` es la estructura, y `(*ap).x` y `(*ap).y` son los mienbros. Para emplear `ap`, se podría escribir, por ejemplo,

```
struct punto origen, *ap

ap = &origen;
printf("el origen es (%d, %d)\n", (*ap).x, (*ap).y);
```

Los paréntesis son necesarios en `(*pp).x` debido a que la precedencia del operador miembro de estructura `.` es mayor que la de `*`. La expresión `*pp.x` significa `*(pp.x)`, lo cual es ilegal debido a que `x` no es un apuntador.

Ahora, los apuntadores a estructuras se usan con tanta frecuencia qeu se ha proporcionado una notación alternativa como abreviación. Si `p` es un apuntador a estructura, entonces:

```
p -> miembro de estructura
```

se refiere al miembro en particular. (El operador `->` es un signo menos seguido por `>`). De esta manera podríamos haber esfrito

```
printf("el origen es (%d, %d)\n", ap->x, ap->y);
```